# SqliteCipher peculiar behaviour

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using SqliteCipher for Windows.

I am using it in my C# Windows forms application. My code is some thing like

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT rcno from blockftins where status='0' and rcno >" + lastrcno + " and rcno <=" + goupto + " Limit 1";
var readerftin = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (readerftin.Read())
{
    //starts from a specific record
    lastrcno = readerftin.GetInt32(0);
}
```

The table has 17391 records. When my lastrcno is set to 17390 and goupto is 17391, it fails to retrieve any record.

However if I run the resultant code by capturing it in Textvisualier in sqlite command prompt, i get lastrecno as 17391, which is the correct answer.

The code captured from Textvisualized is -

```
SELECT rcno 
FROM blockftins 
WHERE status = '0' AND rcno > 17390 AND rcno <=17391 LIMIT 1
```

Any reason for this peculiar behavior?

It seems the problem is with last two records -

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT rcno from blockftins where status='0'  and rcno <=" + 17390 + " Limit 1";/
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT rcno from blockftins where status='0'  and rcno <=" + 17391 + " Limit 1";/
```

fetches no recor.
However

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT rcno from blockftins where status='0'  and rcno <=" + 17389 + " Limit 1";/
```

retrieves the correct  record.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same database?

Comment: yes they are same database.

Comment: What is your evidence for that? What you have shown would indicate that you are using different databases.

Comment: I am sure the database is same and the query     select count(rcno) from blockftins retrieves 17391 records both at Windowsform and sqlite command prompt. Another point is if I set lastrcno to 17388 then only the Windowsform application retrieves a record. It works for all numbers smaller than that.